# Get device image scale (e.g. @1x, @2x and @3x)

Tags: ios, image, swift, scale, retina-display

I have an app that uses a service to get some icons.

With this service I can get any image of any size, so I've planned to get the 3 images (@1x, @2x and @3x) and store them on the BBDD, and then get the scale to use one of these three; or maybe get only the one according with the device scale.

But the thing is, how can I get the device scale (@1x, @2x and @3x) programmatically?

Both Obj-c and Swift are welcomed ;)

Comment: `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;`

Comment: @iphonic that works ;) how could be so easy hehe, thanks! post it as an answer and i'll check it as answered

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

this will give you the exact scale as per device.

In **Swift 3**

```
UIScreen.main.scale
```

Cheers.

Comment: yes =)    UIScreen.mainScreen().scale   for the Swift lovers